# Extract timings within iframe from webpage

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract timings from this [page](https://www.capmetro.org/planner/?language=en_US&P=SQ&input=Museum%20Station%20(SB),%20Stop%20ID%205866&start=yes&widget=1.0.0&). I would like these timings in text form to do more processing.

[image]

I have tried this code:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="lyr_timeCount")
for elem in elements:
    times.append(elem.text)
```

using the selenium driver. However, elements is an empty list. I have also tried using the xPath with the same result. I have also tried this using beautiful soup with the same result.

```
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
times = soup.find_all('time', {'class': 'lyr_sqResTime'})
```

Both have resulted in empty lists. How can I extract the timing data from this webpage using either method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing elements are within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the visibility of all the desired elements.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.capmetro.org/planner/?language=en_US&P=SQ&input=Museum%20Station%20(SB),%20Stop%20ID%205866&start=yes&widget=1.0.0&')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='Trip Planner']")))
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.lyr_timeCount")))])
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://www.capmetro.org/planner/?language=en_US&P=SQ&input=Museum%20Station%20(SB),%20Stop%20ID%205866&start=yes&widget=1.0.0&')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='Trip Planner']")))
    print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='lyr_timeCount ']")))])
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['4 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '7 min\nMinutes', '16 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '20 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '21 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '23 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '37 min\nMinutes', '37 min\nMinutes', '39 min\nMinutes\nconfirmed', '42 min', '4:43 PM', '4:53 PM', '4:53 PM', '5:03 PM', '5:03 PM', '5:13 PM', '5:13 PM', '5:23 PM', '5:23 PM', '5:33 PM', '5:33 PM', '5:43 PM', '5:43 PM', '5:53 PM', '5:53 PM', '6:03 PM', '6:08 PM', '6:13 PM', '6:23 PM', '6:23 PM', '6:33 PM', '6:38 PM', '6:38 PM', '6:43 PM', '6:50 PM', '6:53 PM', '6:58 PM', '7:05 PM', '7:08 PM', '7:13 PM']
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```